# Questa interminabile estate siccitosa!

Tags: word-usage

***[Siccitoso](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/siccitoso/)*** è una parola poco comune tornata recentemente alla ribalta con il gran caldo di quest'estate. I [media](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=jV6DWe-cNIvPwAL39rnADQ&q=estate%20siccitosa%20&oq=estate%20siccitosa%20&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...4160.9816.0.10096.27.27.0.4.4.0.292.4202.0j26j1.27.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..8.18.2352.3..0j41j0i67k1j0i30k1j0i131k1j0i3k1j0i22i30k1.HXOGDj63IPU) ne stanno facendo gran uso e guardando con [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=siccitoso%2Csiccitosa&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csiccitoso%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csiccitosa%3B%2Cc0) quando diffuso fosse questo  termine ho scoperto che era abbastanza usato negli anni '50, per poi essere praticamente dimenticato nei decenni successivi.

Qualcuno riesce a spiegare l'improvvisa popolarità del termine, praticamente dall'immediato dopoguerra?

E fino a qualche anno fa, invece che siccitoso, che termini si usavano?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A quanto pare](http://forum.meteonetwork.it/meteorologia/105813-calde-estati-degli-anni-40-50-a.html), il picco del grafico in corrispondenza degli anni '50 si spiega in modo analogo al recente ritorno in uso della parola. Infatti un tale caldo in quegli anni era ancora più straordinario, il che giustifica l'assoluta singolarità di quel picco (subito dopo si va in caduta libera).

Sinonimi di *siccitoso* sono [*arido*](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.ilmessaggero.it/AMP/meteo_caldo_caronte-2546796.html&ved=0ahUKEwjxyITE-r_VAhVLXRQKHeWDA9I4ChAWCBswAA&usg=AFQjCNFq849hq_tw0c4anyjMYJHsZx44bA&ampcf=1), e soprattutto [*torrido*](http://www.leggo.it/AMP/caronte_estate_bollente_2017_emergenza_siccita-2518978.html), tra l'altro spesso **abusato** nell'indicare caldo umido (grazie ad @egreg per avermi ricordato di precisarlo). Il primo d'altronde, di solito, è riservato a descrivere condizioni peggiori di quelle italiane, mentre nel contesto italiano e simili *torrido* è il termine più usato. Entrambe le mie affermazioni sono confermate dal confronto dei [grafici](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=siccitoso%2Csiccitosa%2C+torrido%2C+torrida%2C+arido%2C+arida&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csiccitoso%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csiccitosa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctorrido%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctorrida%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carido%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carida%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: C'è da dire che *torrido* è abusato, quando indica caldo umido.

Comment: @egreg: Vero! Grazie, avevo dimenticato di sottolinearlo.